# String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.discrepancy of date format?

Tags: c#, sql

I try several things but still this is showing.
here is my codes:

```
        string conString = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-PC;Initial Catalog=EmployeeData;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
        {
            string hday = textBox5.Text;
            DateTime hday2 = Convert.ToDateTime(hday,System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("hi-IN").DateTimeFormat);


            SqlCommand Query = new SqlCommand("Update EmpTab SET FirstName = @fn, LastName = @ln, HireDate = @hday, Gender = @g, YWC = @months, Status = @stat WHERE EmployeeID = @EID", con);
            Query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EID", comboBox1.Text);
            Query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fn", textBox2.Text);
            Query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ln", textBox3.Text);

            Query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hday",hday2);
            Query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@g", textBox6.Text);
            Query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@months", textBox7.Text);
            Query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stat", textBox8.Text);
            con.Open();
            Query.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("You have successfully saved the data");
        }
```

Comment: What is the type of `HireDate` column and what is the value of `hday2` exactly?

Comment: If `HireDate` is `datetime` or `datetime2` then you're doing the right thing by passing a `DateTime` through a parameter. No string formatting will be involved, so I'd start looking at the *other* columns/parameters. But please also read [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: Can you confirm that the strings from the other textboxes are definitely not longer than the respective column lengths in the database? That's usually what that error means.

Comment: yes,all other textboxes are fine...my database for hiredate is date,is that wrong data type?

Comment: What is the table definition? Can you include example data that reproduces this?

Comment: The Date type shouldn't be a problem (it will remove the time component on insertion). Can you replace that hday2 line with `Query.Parameters.Add("@hday", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = hday2;`? If that still doesn't work, can you run profiler and update the question with the offending line? There must be a strange conversion going on.

Comment: still same error, if i change my code like this:
                Query.Parameters.Add("@hday", textBox5.Text);                             and remove this:                                                                                      string hday = textBox5.Text;
            DateTime hday2 = Convert.ToDateTime(hday,System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("hi-IN").DateTimeFormat);                                                                 it shows this error message:Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Yeah that would not work because implicit conversions from string to datetime is very particular about the format it accepts. Do you have access to SQL profiler? Seeing the generated insert statement will be a big help

Comment: Also, what value is in hday2?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in your database you have `varchar/nvarchar` field which have symbols restriction and you are trying to put bigger string in this field. Also if the problem occurs for field which should be date, you should use datetime db field type not `nvarchar/varchar` and provide DateTime field as `SqlCommand` parameter.